# Custom Application or Web Parts? No idea how to do either

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, data-view-web-part, content-editor-web-part

In my team, I've been tasked into automating some of the things we do. I have been playing around with SharePoint (I don't have full overall SharePoint admin privileges though, although I do own the site).

Let me provide an overall context. We've a lot of projects going on in the company. Collection of these projects is called 'RELEASE'. We track 'status' of each project and then create weekly reports based on status of each project. Based on status of each project, we derive overall status of the release.

So, what we are trying to do is create a page that does the following:

1. First, it shows **overall status** of the release (**color coded and auto-calculated**) along with some text-description manually entered.
2. Below that, it shows a **list of all projects** along with status of each project
3. Below that, it shows **calendar view** of above list
4. Below that, some **text to be entered by page owner**.

See image for a *rough layout*.

[image: Image Rough Layout]

This list of projects may also be referenced in other SharePoint pages.

So far, it looks like **WebParts** is the way to go. But I couldn't figure out a way to setup such a web-part. How to get list view, how to get calendar view in web-parts? What web-part (or content type) for each of the four element?

**Any help or advise will be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, it would likely be something like this:

1. Content Query Web Part or possibly even KPI Web Parts (though those
   are deprecated in 2013)
2. Simple List view Web part, tailored for whatever fields are to be shown
3. Create a Calendar view on the desired list, add a List View Web Part for that list and switch it to the calendar view.
4. Content Editor Web Part

As with all things SharePoint, that is just *one* way to do it among probably dozens.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this. But in Content Query Web Part - how will I "auto-calculate" overall status (based on list that will be shown in next web part - List).  

Also, when I add List in web-part, I am unable to tailor it. All I see is a blank list with all the fields/columns missing. Evethough, the list contains items.

Comment: the Xsl used by the CQWP can be customized to include any calculation that Xsl itself is capable of.  As long as you can expose the raw data in some way you should be able to calculate the state in the Xsl - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx